# Firebase admin SDK With Java, failed to parse

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am new to firebase development, I tried to push a simple string to firebase realtime db, but keep getting error.

My code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        initializeFirebase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRootRef = database.getReference();
    DatabaseReference condRef = myRootRef.child("condition");

    condRef.setValueAsync("ok", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError arg0, DatabaseReference arg1) {
            System.out.println("success");
        }
    });

}

private static void initializeFirebase() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("adarofirebase.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://adarofirebase.firebaseio.com/").build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
}
```

error stack trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException:
Failed to parse node with class class com.arya.firebase.App$1
```

I've been figuring it out all day but still no luck. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `setValueAsync()` method with wrong arguments:

[`public ApiFuture<Void> setValueAsync(Object value, Object priority)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValueAsync(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))

The second argument is `priority`, which should be a JSON-parseable value. You're passing a `CompletionListener`, which is not JSON-parseable.

Comment: oh i see, but if you check the firebase admin sdk guide, in the adding completion callback section, they put CompletionListener as a second argument. so probably the guide is not up to date yet?

Comment: I think you're right. That sample should use the `setValue()` method instead of `setValueAsync()`. I've filed a bug to update the documentation. Thanks for pointing it out.